# How to strip everything except digits from a string in Scala (quick one liners)

Tags: scala, filter

This is driving me nuts... there **must** be a way to strip out all non-digit characters (or perform other simple filtering) in a String.

Example: I want to turn a phone number ("+72 (93) 2342-7772" or "+1 310-777-2341") into a simple numeric String (not an Int), such as "729323427772" or "13107772341".

I tried `"[\\d]+".r.findAllIn(phoneNumber)` which returns an Iteratee and then I would have to recombine them into a String somehow... seems horribly wasteful.

I also came up with: `phoneNumber.filter("0123456789".contains(_))` **but** that becomes tedious for other situations. For instance, removing all punctuation... I'm really after something that works with a regular expression so it has wider application than just filtering out digits.

Anyone have a fancy Scala one-liner for this that is more direct?

Comment: Should probably use "555" like in the movies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` and Regex.

`"+72 (93) 2342-7772".replaceAll("[^0-9]", "") // res1: String = 729323427772`

Comment: As a note, you can also use `\D` instead of `[^0-9]`.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `filter`, treating the string as a character sequence and testing the character with `isDigit`:

```
"+72 (93) 2342-7772".filter(_.isDigit) // res0: String = 729323427772
```

Comment: Thank you... simple answer... but, since I'm specifically looking for a regex solution, I accepted @Spork's – thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, define the collection of *valid* characters, in this case

```
val d = '0' to '9'
```

and so for `val a = "+72 (93) 2342-7772"`, filter on collection inclusion for instance with either of these,

```
for (c <- a if d.contains(c)) yield c

a.filter(d.contains)

a.collect{ case c if d.contains(c) => c }
```